# What does it mean "two-digit act of congress?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Rhea Perlman, diminutive Cheers bartendress (and queen of spades), has
>   been caught cavorting with the seven-foot-seven Sudanese basketball
>   star Manute Bol (seven of clubs) in a highly explicit (and in this
>   case, anatomically improbable) **two-digit act of congress** (three of
>   clubs). (For more, see [here](https://www.recommendmeabook.com/joshuafoer/moonwalkingwitheinstein))

I've tried too many times to understand it, googled it and still don't understand fully this sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a fairly thick pun. An "act of Congress" most commonly refers to a law passed by the legislative branch of the United States Government. Here though, it means a sexual activity ("sexual congress" is an old-fashioned name for sex).

The specific activity is probably mutual oral sex, for which "69" (a two-digit number) is common slang. This also explains the "anatomical improbability" since a large height difference between partners makes this activity more difficult.

Comment: Ah ha! Much better answer than mine! (I should have tried a few more assumptions...)

Answer (score 1):

Where on earth did you read this?

In this context 'act of congress' probably means some sort of sexual act, and digit would mean fingers.

Beyond that, as Newton said, I make no assumptions.